# Automatic persisted query in Apollo Client and Server is not working getting PERSISTED_QUERY_NOT_FOUND error

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server, apollostack

I tried to use highly advertised Automatic persisted query for performance benefits in Graphql based system but after spending three days I couldn't fix below problem. Apollo documents has lots of 404 pages for this topic if you try to look up  -

**On Client:**

I used

```
import { createPersistedQueryLink } from "apollo-link-persisted-queries";


const httpLink = createHttpLink({uri: API_URL })


const apqSwitch = createPersistedQueryLink({useGETForHashedQueries: true}).concat(httpLink);

  let links = [errorlink, stateLink, setSiteIdHeaderLink, apqLinkSwitch]

  const link = ApolloLink.from(links)

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    defaultOptions: {
      watchQuery: {
        errorPolicy: 'all'
      },
      query: {
        errorPolicy: 'all'
      },
      mutate: {
        errorPolicy: 'all'
      }
    },
    link,
    cache,
    connectToDevTools: true,
    credentials: 'include',
  })

  return { client, persistor }
}
```

**client dependencies:**

```
"apollo-boost": "^0.1.22",
"apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.3.11",
"apollo-cache-persist": "^0.1.1",
"apollo-client": "^2.4.7",
"apollo-link": "^1.2.3",
"apollo-link-batch-http": "^1.2.8",
"apollo-link-http": "^1.5.9",
"apollo-link-persisted-queries": "^0.2.2",
"apollo-link-retry": "^2.2.5",
"apollo-link-schema": "^1.1.1",
```

**On Server:**

```
import { InMemoryLRUCache } from 'apollo-server-caching';
const { RedisCache } = require('apollo-server-cache-redis');

const server = new ApolloServer({
  ...root,
  resolverValidationOptions: {
    requireResolversForResolveType: false,
  },
  persistedQueries: {
    /*
    cache: new CustomRedis(),
    */
    cache: new RedisCache({
      host: 'localhost',
      port: xxxx,
    }),
  },
  formatError,
  formatResponse: (response, query) => formatResponse({ response, query }),
  dataSources
});
```

**Server dependencies:**

```
"apollo-datasource-rest": "^0.3.2",
"apollo-errors": "^1.9.0",
"apollo-server-cache-redis": "^0.3.1",
"apollo-server-caching": "^0.3.1",
"apollo-server-express": "^2.4.8",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"dataloader": "^1.4.0",
"express": "^4.16.3",
"glob": "^7.1.3",
"graphql": "^14.0.2",
"graphql-import": "^0.7.1",
"graphql-resolvers": "^0.2.2",
```

**Observations:**

1. From client side I see sha1 has is being send to server.

variables=%7B%7D&extensions=%7B%22persistedQuery%22%3A%7B%22version%22%3A1%2C%22sha256Hash%22%3A%22fd4c5f1ae3sfsf6ee0f0710b8d303a9703db7a6708b401278e2fd664f56f4e91762f%22%7D%7D

2. Server is looking for sha1 in the redis cache but it couldn't find
3. Server returns PersistedQueryNotFound","MsgCode":"PERSISTED_QUERY_NOT_FOUND 
   error to client

After that nothing happens there is no set operation is performed in redis cache and continuously getting PERSISTED_QUERY_NOT_FOUND error

**Issue:**
APQ is not working, continuously getting PersistedQueryNotFound error

Answer (score 1):

I have also configured APQs, and they are working as expected.

Can you please try below code at `client` side? Server side is pretty much same as I have.

```
import { createPersistedQueryLink } from "apollo-link-persisted-queries";
import { createHttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import ApolloClient from "apollo-client";

const link = createPersistedQueryLink({useGETForHashedQueries: true}).concat(createHttpLink({ uri: "/graphql" }));

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: link,
});
```

This is documented [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/apq/)!

Comment: How do i pass Query Signature in request ? 
const test = {
  operationName: 'MyQuery',
  variables: null,
  extensions: {
    persistedQuery: {
      version: 1,
      sha256Hash: hashOfQuery
    }
  }
}
await client.query(test);

Comment: That will be taken care by Apollo client , you need to use `createPersistedQueryLink` for getting it done.

Comment: but for me some queries works fine but some of them are throwing this error. to this what yoga-server docs suggested didn't worked. https://the-guild.dev/graphql/yoga-server/docs/features/automatic-persisted-queries